# How to arrange df.plot.line() into subplots

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, subplot

I have several DF with only numerical columns. I'm using df.plot.line() to see the data and it works fine as it plots graphs separately.

Now I'm trying a way to arrange those graphs into a subplot but I can't find a way.

here is an example:

```
df_km_cumsum.plot.line(figsize=[20,15],legend=False)
```

gives this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wL0I.png)

```
df_daytot_km.plot.line(figsize=[20,15],legend=False)
```

gives this other [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycJnr.png)

Now I'd like to put them inside a 2x1 figure to make them see together.

Any help is kindly accepted.
Thank you

Comment: Can you give some example of what you have and what you want? I think it should be possible using the "x" and "y" args of df.plot.line: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.line.html

Comment: I've edited the original post including examples. Tell me if its clearer now. thank you.

Comment: create the subplots using `matplotlib` (`fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)`), then use the `ax` kward when using `plot.line` (`df_km_cumsum.plot.line(figsize=[20,15],legend=False, ax=ax1)`)

Comment: doing this:
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)

df_km_cumsum.plot.line(figsize=[10,5],legend=False,ax=ax1)

df_daytot_km.plot.line(figsize=[20,15],legend=False,ax=ax2)

but gives me only blank sublot, and doesnt fill them with the graphs

Comment: oh, you probably want to remove the `figsize` argument to `plot.line` and add that to `plt.subplots` instead

Comment: I would create a single df and call `plot(sublots=True)`, it will draw lines by default

Comment: yes it worked! Thankyou :)
 
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,figsize=[20,15])
df_km_cumsum.plot.line(legend=False, ax=ax1)
df_dayavg_km.plot.line(legend=False, ax=ax2)
plt.show()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @tmdavision, here is the final solution:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,figsize=[20,15])

df_km_cumsum.plot.line(legend=False, ax=ax1)

df_dayavg_km.plot.line(legend=False, ax=ax2)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
df_km_cumsum.plot.line(figsize=[20,15],legend=False)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
df_daytot_km.plot.line(figsize=[20,15],legend=False)
```

Comment: hi Piero, thank you for your answer but i've tried it before and doesn't work. Gives me a white subplot.